# Crystal Report how to change the display order in a group

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report like below image:

[image]

The report is group by "Quot No.", by default it's ordered by "Times Used" (8th column)

How can I change the ordering so that it will order by "Total amount"?

The total amount is a field in the report which is the sum of a field named "quotamt" in the datasource:

[image]

I've tried looking in the change group options, took a look at the "Use a formula as group sort order", but the formula only provides three options (ascending, descending, original order), and is unable to sort by another column

[image]

The desired result is:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: It is needed on conditional basis or permanent.

Comment: @Ajay2707 it's needed on conditional basis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I suggest, rather than doing this task in crystal report, good to done at sqlserver side means database side.

This is simplest suggestion when you have this type of situation.

You can give the condition on sqlserver side too. and get the data order same as you want.

Yes, this can be done in report side, but it take time for this.

Comment: Good. if you stuck anywhere, just ask again. or ping me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use formula as group sort order instead from the dropdown use `Specifed Order` and in the window specify the order you need